# EGit: Failed (SignatureException) to execute: Signature encoding error

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I'm getting the following error when I pull or push code from GIT.

```
Failed (SignatureException) to execute: Signature encoding error
```

Comment: Git is not involved here: this appears to be an EGit + ssh configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while to find a simple solution.

***You can try either one of the following:***

***Solution 1:***

1. go to your ssh folder (`cd  ~/.ssh/`)
2. check if you have a `config` file or else create one file with the name `config` and copy the below details.

[image: My current ssh folder structure]

```
Host github.foo.com
Hostname github.foo.com
User git
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your_private_key
HostKeyAlgorithms ^rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
```

(Replace the hostname and the path to the key as appropriate.)

In my case, I'm trying to access the IBM GitHub repository. and my private key file name is `id_rsa`

Example:

```
Host github.ibm.com
Hostname github.ibm.com
User git
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms ^rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
```

***Solution 2:***

1. go to your ssh folder (`cd  ~/.ssh/`)
2. Back up your `known_hosts` file in some other location (or rename it. for example: in the above screenshot, I changed it to known_hosts_1), and delete it.

Now try to git pull or push from the EGit.
[image: save keys in known_hosts file]

***Solution 3:***
If ***Solution 1:*** and ***Solution 2:***  does not work individually try both solutions together. i.e create a `config` file and also delete/rename `known_hosts` file.

More detailed discussion is on:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1108282/

Comment: But what was the problem?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Issue was when we use git pull, or push using Egit in eclipse it used to show an error saying `Failed (SignatureException) to execute: Signature encoding error`

Comment: First solution totally worked for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and I resolved this by upgrading eGit to version "Git integration for Eclipse  6.4.0.202211300538-r"